# Convert and Append string into existing byte array

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I am working on converting and existing C# project over to Java/Android. I am looking for the Java equivalent to [UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6z64h.aspx). Take a look at the C# code below, how do I add the string packet into the data byte array? I have looked at the String.getBytes() method but it is not the same.

```
int length = packet.Length;

byte[] data = new byte[6 + length + 1];
data[0] = (byte)VAR1;
data[1] = 1;

**Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(packet, 0, length, data, 6);**

data[6 + length] = (byte)VAR2;

data[5] = (byte)(length % 256);
length /= 256;
data[4] = (byte)(length % 256);
length /= 256;
data[3] = (byte)(length % 256);
length /= 256;
data[2] = (byte)(length % 256);
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that you can get all of the UTF-8-encoded data into the same number of bytes as there are characters. That's simply not true, unless all the characters are ASCII.

Comment: @JonSkeet, they are all ASCII. All characters that can be found in the string "packet" are "predefined".

Comment: In that case, why specify UTF-8? Why not use Encoding.ASCII, which is a lot clearer in intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, given that you mean ASCII rather than UTF-8, there are two immediate options:

**Intermediate byte array**

```
byte[] encodedText = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.arraycopy(encodedText, 0, data, 6, encodedText.length);
```

This is inefficient, but simple.

**Charset directly**

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newEncoder();
CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(text);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data, 6, data.length - 6);
encoder.encode(charBuffer, byteBuffer, true);
```

This is *possibly* more efficient, but more complicated to understand.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet, that worked a charm. The System.arraycopy was what I needed. Honestly, for my proposes the encoding specification is irrelevant.

Comment: @user1017477: It's really not - because if you specify something like EBCDIC or UTF-16, you won't get the bytes you expect. Encodings are *never* irrelevant.

Comment: I understand what you're saying however, in this case all of the text that is to be converted is essentially "hard coded". I have run your suggestion through a handful of possible scenarios without specifying the encoding type of getBytes() and everything is functioning as it should.

Comment: @user1017477: That just means you haven't run it on a system where the default encoding is inhospitable to you. It doesn't mean such code isn't broken.

Comment: you are correct again. I guess by working on apps that only target a small subset of users within a controlled environment, one can overlook the ramifications of running the same app on a larger scale?

Comment: @user1017477: You might be able to get away with it - just like you *might* be able to get away with building SQL dynamically rather than using parameterized SQL if you happen to only have nice users. That doesn't mean it's a good habit to get into. It's not like specifying the encoding is hard, and it's a *good* thing in that it forces you to think about the conversion you're performing.